# Wordpress unSlider issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to get `unlider.js` working on Wordpress. My guess is that the registration of the script is not working properly.

I am using a child theme, and this is the code I put in `functions.php` to register the script (taken from WP guide).

Clearly, I am doing something wrong, perhaps the script is being inserted before jQuery.

What is the best way to attach a script from a child theme, after jQuery?

One I have so far is this:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_add_scripts' );
function child_add_scripts() {
wp_register_script(
    'google-analytics',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/unslider.js',
    array( 'jquery' ),
    false,
    '1.0',
    true
    );
wp_enqueue_script( 'google-analytics' );
}
?>
```

Comment: It seems though that if I reload the page continously, the slider appears briefly and then is covered up with blank space.

Comment: removing all the content except the slider makes it render, but the script is not working - the slider is just plain html

Comment: You should check your Firebug console for any error messages.

Comment: Are you sure your script is loaded? In your sample code you are referring to your stylesheet directory. Is this where unslider.js is located?
Check your source code in firebug for errors, and click the link for unslider.js in your source code to check if it links to the correct file.

Comment: the error I get is "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'unslider", which looks like the script is not loaded correctly. I have the script both in parent and child theme, just in case, but none of them seems to be working. All unslider files have been checked before and tested separately from WP.